# Event does not trigger using javafx and mvvmfx

Tags: java, javafx, mvvmfx

I' trying to build an application using javafx and mvvmfx framework to compute and display [CVRP Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_routing_problem) but when I add an event listener on a Circle, it is never triggered.

```
scope.subscribe("STOP_LOADED", (key, payload) -> {
        stepList.clear();
        stopList.clear();
        Stop depot = CVRPGraph.getDepot();
        stopList.add(new Circle(toUiUnit(depot.getX()), toUiUnit(depot.getY()), 3, Color.BLACK));
        stopList.addAll(CVRPGraph.getClientList().stream()
                .map(stop -> {
                    Circle circle = new Circle(toUiUnit(stop.getX()), toUiUnit(stop.getY()), 3, Color.RED);
                    circle.setOnMouseClicked(mouseEvent -> System.out.println(mouseEvent.getEventType().getName()));
                    return circle;
                })
                .collect(Collectors.toList()));
    });
```

stopList is initialize like this

```
private final ObservableList<Circle> stopList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
```

which I fullfill in the viewmodel and in the view I observe an change like this

```
graphViewModel.stopList().addListener((ListChangeListener<? super Circle>) change -> {
            stopGroup.getChildren().clear();
            stopGroup.getChildren().addAll(change.getList());
        });
```

where stopGroup is javafx.scene.Group

```
@FXML
private Group stopGroup;
```

Circle are displayed but when I click on it nothing is print

[Program screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLw4P.png)
What I am doing wrong ?

P.S. You can find the entire code here https://github.com/ptourneur/CapacitatedVehicleRoutingProblem but do not hesitate if you need more information thanks

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. For instance, what is `stopList`?

Comment: nobody wants to wade through tons of unrelated code - strip it down to the most minimal example that still demonstrates the problem (as suggested by @Slaw) and post it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your example app is a misconfigured layout. Your usage of the AnchorPane is wrong. Your "ParamView.fxml" is covering the whole app window even though it's only visible on the right side. And therefor it is also consuming all mouse events. If you remove the paramsview the clickhandlers are working as expected. For debugging you could add visual borders to your container components to see how much space they are really using.
If you use AnchorPane your should normally also use AnchorPane.bottomAnchor, topAnchor and so on.

Comment: Thanks a lot, can't believe I did not think about that. I generate the ui with SceneBuilder but I will refactor it